Unable to access mount directory macfuse
I have a filesystem with the code below which runs well in my ubuntu virtual machine, but for some reason, is giving issues when i try testing it on my mac. I am mounting using the command
./fileSystem -d /Users/redhunter/Desktop/myFolder/mount

However, when I try to cd into the mounted folder to perform any file system operations, i get the error:

cd: Input/output error: mount

Here's my filesystem without my detailed FUSE function defitions:
#include "FS.h"

static struct fuse_operations fsoperations =
{
    .getattr=fsgetattr,
    .mkdir=fsmkdir,
    .readdir=fsreaddir,
    .open=fsopen,
    .read=fsread,
    .create=fscreate,
    .write=fswrite,
    .release=fsrelease,
};


void initialize_superblock(){
    memset(spblock.data_bitmap, '0', 100*sizeof(char));
    memset(spblock.inode_bitmap, '0', 100*sizeof(char));
}


void tree_to_array(filetype * queue, int * front, int * rear, int * index){

    if(rear < front)
        return;
    if(*index > 30)
        return;


    filetype curr_node = queue[*front];
    *front += 1;
    file_array[*index] = curr_node;
    *index += 1;

    if(*index < 6){

        if(curr_node.valid){
            int n = 0;
            int i;
            for(i = 0; i < curr_node.num_children; i++){
                if(*rear < *front)
                    *rear = *front;
                queue[*rear] = *(curr_node.children[i]);
                *rear += 1;
            }
            while(i<5){
                filetype waste_node;
                waste_node.valid = 0;
                queue[*rear] = waste_node;
                *rear += 1;
                i++;
            }
        }
        else{
            int i = 0;
            while(i<5){
                filetype waste_node;
                waste_node.valid = 0;
                queue[*rear] = waste_node;
                *rear += 1;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    tree_to_array(queue, front, rear, index);

}


int save_contents(){
    printf("Saving file\n");
    filetype * queue = malloc(sizeof(filetype)*60);
    int front = 0;
    int rear = 0;
    queue[0] = *root;
    int index = 0;
    tree_to_array(queue, &front, &rear, &index);

    for(int i = 0; i < 31; i++){
        printf("%d", file_array[i].valid);
    }

    FILE * fd = fopen("file_structure.bin", "wb");

    FILE * fd1 = fopen("super.bin", "wb");

    fwrite(file_array, sizeof(filetype)*31, 1, fd);
    fwrite(&spblock,sizeof(superblock),1,fd1);

    fclose(fd);
    fclose(fd1);

    printf("\n");
}

void initialize_root_directory() {

    spblock.inode_bitmap[1]=1; //marking it with 0
    root = (filetype *) malloc (sizeof(filetype));

    strcpy(root->path, "/");
    strcpy(root->name, "/");

    root -> children = NULL;
    root -> num_children = 0;
    root -> parent = NULL;
    root -> num_links = 2;
    root -> valid = 1;
    strcpy(root->test, "test");
    strcpy(root -> type, "directory");

    root->c_time = time(NULL);
    root->a_time = time(NULL);
    root->m_time = time(NULL);
    root->b_time = time(NULL);

    root -> permissions = S_IFDIR | 0777;

    root -> size = 0;
    root->group_id = getgid();
    root->user_id = getuid();

    root -> number = 2;
    root -> blocks = 0;

    save_contents();
}

filetype * filetype_from_path(char * path){
    char curr_folder[100];
    char * path_name = malloc(strlen(path) + 2);

    strcpy(path_name, path);

    filetype * curr_node = root;

    fflush(stdin);

    if(strcmp(path_name, "/") == 0)
        return curr_node;

    if(path_name[0] != '/'){
        printf("INCORRECT PATH\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        path_name++;
    }

    if(path_name[strlen(path_name)-1] == '/'){
        path_name[strlen(path_name)-1] = '\0';
    }

    char * index;
    int flag = 0;

    while(strlen(path_name) != 0){
        index = strchr(path_name, '/');
        
        if(index != NULL){
            strncpy(curr_folder, path_name, index - path_name);
            curr_folder[index-path_name] = '\0';
            
            flag = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < curr_node -> num_children; i++){
                if(strcmp((curr_node -> children)[i] -> name, curr_folder) == 0){
                    curr_node = (curr_node -> children)[i];
                    flag = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag == 0)
                return NULL;
        }
        else{
            strcpy(curr_folder, path_name);
            flag = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < curr_node -> num_children; i++){
                if(strcmp((curr_node -> children)[i] -> name, curr_folder) == 0){
                    curr_node = (curr_node -> children)[i];
                    return curr_node;
                }
            }
            return NULL;
        }
        path_name = index+1;
    }

}

int find_free_inode(){
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i++){
        if(spblock.inode_bitmap[i] == '0'){
            spblock.inode_bitmap[i] = '1';
        }
        return i;
    }
}

int find_free_db(){
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++){
        if(spblock.inode_bitmap[i] == '0'){
            spblock.inode_bitmap[i] = '1';
        }
        return i;
    }
}

void add_child(filetype * parent, filetype * child){
    (parent -> num_children)++;

    parent -> children = realloc(parent -> children, (parent -> num_children)*sizeof(filetype *));

    (parent -> children)[parent -> num_children - 1] = child;
}


static int fsgetattr(const char *path, struct stat *statit) {
    char *pathname;
    pathname=(char *)malloc(strlen(path) + 2);

    strcpy(pathname, path);

    printf("GETATTR %s\n", pathname);

    filetype * file_node = filetype_from_path(pathname);
    if(file_node == NULL)
        return -ENOENT;

    statit->st_uid = file_node -> user_id; // The owner of the file/directory is the user who mounted the filesystem
    statit->st_gid = file_node -> group_id; // The group of the file/directory is the same as the group of the user who mounted the filesystem
    statit->st_atime = file_node -> a_time; // The last "a"ccess of the file/directory is right now
    statit->st_mtime = file_node -> m_time; // The last "m"odification of the file/directory is right now
    statit->st_ctime = file_node -> c_time;
    statit->st_mode = file_node -> permissions;
    statit->st_nlink = file_node -> num_links + file_node -> num_children;
    statit->st_size = file_node -> size;
    statit->st_blocks = file_node -> blocks;

    return 0;
}


static int fsmkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    ...
}


int fsreaddir(const char *path, void *buffer, fuse_fill_dir_t filler, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi ){
    ...
}


int fscreate(const char *path, mode_t mode, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    ...
}



int fsopen(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    ...
}


int fsread(const char *path, char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset,struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    ...
}


int fswrite(const char *path, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t offset, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    ...
}


static int fsrelease(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi) {
    ...
}


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    FILE *fd = fopen("file_structure.bin", "rb");
    if(fd){
    printf("LOADING\n");
    fread(&file_array, sizeof(filetype)*31, 1, fd);

    int child_startindex = 1;
    file_array[0].parent = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        file_array[i].num_children = 0;
        file_array[i].children = NULL;
        for(int j = child_startindex; j < child_startindex + 5; j++){
            if(file_array[j].valid){
                add_child(&file_array[i], &file_array[j]);
            }
        }
        child_startindex += 5;
    }

        root = &file_array[0];

        FILE *fd1 = fopen("super.bin", "rb");
        fread(&spblock,sizeof(superblock),1,fd1);
    }
    else{
        initialize_superblock();
        initialize_root_directory();
    }

    return fuse_main(argc, argv, &fsoperations, NULL);
}

